# Find string starting with a word, ending with another in the same line with regular expressions

Tags: regex

can you help me in finding string pattern in text file? I mean, for example, I have got a file:

```
The model of operation is that an internet module resides in each host
engaged in internet communication and in each gateway that
interconnects networks.
```

And I want to find string starting with word `model`, and ending at word `each` in first line, how to do it? 
I have tried with `*.each` But it doesn't found what I wanted to.

Answer (score 3):

The key here is the use of a *non-greedy* expression `.*?`:

```
(?<=\bmodel\b).*?(?=\beach\b)
```

The non-greedy expression ensures the match does not match everything up to the `each` in the second line.

Look-arounds have been used to assert the start and end criteria, *without* consuming them, which means you don't need any grouping to extract the target text - the whole expression *is* the target text.

Answer (score 1):

`\bmodel\b.*\beach\b`

`\b` is a word boundary. It matches if the character before it matches `\W` and the character after matches `\w`, or vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

The following should match what you need

`\<model.*each\>`

Since we are using the beginning of word `\<`, it will not match a string like `supermodel` and since we are ending on word boundary, it will not match string like `beachbum`